# MouseMotion and MouseMotionListener not working

Tags: java, applet, mouse

OK, so I was making a totally normal application and was having problems with MouseMotion and MouseMotionListener: they weren't being called at all in my Canvas. I thought it was something with me adding the Canvas to the Frame, but I created this test program and was very surprised:

```
import java.applet.Applet;
import java.awt.event.MouseMotionListener;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;

import java.awt.Graphics;

public class testapp extends Applet implements MouseMotionListener {
    int x = 40;
    public void mouseMoved(MouseEvent e) {
        showStatus("mouse moved");
    }
    public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent e) {
        showStatus("mouse dragged");
        x++;
        repaint();
    }

    public void paint(Graphics g) {
        g.drawString("Hello World!", 40, x);   //x SHOULD move it down! ugh...
    }
}
```

So I ran this using BlueJ's nice Applet runner and x does not increase when I click and drag my mouse around! The same occurs when I implement MouseListener and try to increase a variable inside one of the implemented methods.

Should I restart my computer? Is my JDK version broken? (I have Java 7 in case this is a known bug)

Right now, I'm super confused and I have an assignment which needs methods to work due tomorrow so any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: 1) Don't use AWT components in this millennium. 2) Applets are not for newbies.  Start with frames.  3) If you instructor is insisting on applets, find a new instructor.

Answer (score 3):

You did not register the component with the listener. Maybe you can try this:

```
   public void init(){
        addMouseMotionListener(this);   
   }
```

Comment: You should review http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/18242/what-is-the-policy-here-on-homework.  :-)

Answer (score 2):

You can't just implement a Listener.  You also have to register it.  Your Applet really has no knowledge that a MouseListener even exists at this point.

Since this is homework, please review http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/mouselistener.html.

Comment: Thank you so much!

Edit: for the record, I knew about this but am currently rather tired and neglected to think about this. Thanks again!